# ER Diagram Design doubts

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, diagram

I have this case where Designers and Managers works on a project with a certain Role.
Is this ER Diagram design correct?
I have doubt in Manager, Designer, Role, and Project relation.
ER Diagram: 
[image: ER Diagram]

Or do I just make it as attribute?
[image]

Here is the Database table Representation
[image: Here is the Database table Representation]

The case also states to show that Administrator manages almost everything.
 Do I have to make a "Manages" relations?

Here is the complete case:
•   Administrators can login to manage everything
•   Managers can login and can work on Projects
•   Designers can also login and can work on Projects
•   Customers own Projects
•   Managers, Designers and Customers have profile pages listing the projects they are related to. Administrator don't have. 
•   Managers can have Designers working for them
•   Designers only have one Manager at a time and Administrator can change the Manager of the Designer at any time
•   Managers and Designers who working on a Project is assigned a Role that the Administrator can manage (e.g. Project Champion, Lead Architect, Safety Engineer, etc)
•   Project needs to have rich text as the description
•   Project needs to be able to have many photos and PDF files
•   Only Managers and Designers who is working on the Project can edit the project (Administrator also can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `Role` an attribute means a `Designer`/`Manager` can only work on a `Project` in a single `Role`. Making it an entity with a cardinality of N in the relationship means a `Designer`/`Manager` can work on a `Project` in multiple `Roles`.

Between those options is the possibility of making it an entity with a cardinality of 1 in the relationship (meaning the PK consists of `Manager`/`Designer` and `Project`). Whether to make it an entity or an attribute depends on whether you have information *about* `Roles` or just want to record a value.

Your question about whether to make a `Manages` relation is unclear - I can't decide for you what "Almost everything" means.

Comment: I guess I will make the cardinality of the `Roles` into 1, which makes it more suitable for this case.
The case states that `Administrator` manages `Manager`, `Designer`, and `Roles` assignment. I have second thoughts about not drawing the `Manages` relations. It will be kind of messy, but I think it is necessary, right?

Comment: It sounds like an explicit requirement, so yes.

Comment: So, I still add the `Manages` relations even though it will have no data inside the database table, right?

Comment: Why wouldn't it have data? If your case requires an administrator to manage the assignments, then I would expect every assignment to indicate the responsible manager.

Comment: Wait, the case says that administrator can manage, but not saying that it is necessary to store data of which administrator responsible for each assignment.
Sorry if I am confusing you, I am confusing myself as well.
I will edit my post and add the complete case

Comment: Based on the case details you added, I think you only need login details so that Administrators and other employees can login. You could model the permissions of different types of employees, or not, either way the restrictions will need to be enforced outside of the data model.